# How to pass 3 arguments instead of 2 in Angular 5 HttpClientModule

Tags: angular

I trying to send 3 parameters to the back-end Router

```
// Function to get user's profile image
getProfileImage(): Observable<Blob>{
  this.createAuthenticationHeaders(); // Create headers before sending to API
  return this._http.get(this.domain + '/authentication/getProfileImageok', this.options, { responseType: "blob" });
}
```

but it said that it only can send two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You can't send three params as per official documentation if you want to send some params you must be attached to options as the second parameter of the get request.

Demo object -

```
get(url: string, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    observe?: HttpObserve;
    params?: HttpParams | {
        [param: string]: string | string[];
    };
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    responseType?: 'arraybuffer' | 'blob' | 'json' | 'text';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
} = {}): Observable<any>
```

For more information refer here.

- https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-httpclient-get-example#get

Comment: i tried `let httpHeaders = new Headers()
                         .set('authorization', this.authToken);
    return this._http.get(this.domain + '/authentication/getProfileImageok',{headers :httpHeaders,
      responseType: "blob"});
  }`but it didn't work

Comment: This should work, Anyways what's the error you are facing now?

Comment: ` error TS2345: Argument of type '{ headers: void; responseType: "blob"; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.
  Types of property 'headers' are incompatible.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }'.`